# Crossed products of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, abelian-groups

I am a Masters student and I am looking at [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02762084). I am apparently really confused by the definition of a parameter set and I was hoping that you could help me. What confuses me is that I tried to contextualise things in an example.

For a field $k$, when we have a finite group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ then $kG$ is a crossed product of $G/N$ with $kN$, and this seems to be a standard fact. In fact, $kG$ is clearly $G/N$-graded, and as unit in each component we can just pick the element that defines the coset in $G/N$ (as group elements are invertible).

(Equivalence classes of) crossed products can be parametrised by parameter sets.
A parameter set is a pair $(\alpha, \gamma)$ where $$\alpha : G/N \to \operatorname{Aut}(kN) \quad , \quad g \mapsto \alpha_g$$
$$\gamma: G/N \times G/N \to \mathcal{U}(kN) \quad , \quad (g,h) \mapsto \gamma(g,h)$$
such that ($\iota_z$ denotes conjugation by $z$ in $kN$)
$$\alpha_g \circ \alpha_h = \iota_{\gamma(g,h)} \circ \alpha_g$$
$$\gamma(g,h)\gamma(gh,k) = \alpha_g(\gamma(h,k))\gamma(g,hk)$$

On page 5 (299 of the journal) we are told how to compute the parameter set associated to a crossed product: choose a set of units $\{u_x\}, x \in G/N$, define $\alpha_x := \iota_{u_g}$ and $\gamma(g,h)=u_g u_h u_{gh}^{-1}$.

So I want to look at this in the smallest possible example. I take $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $N=C_2$. Then let $G_1=C_4$. So $kG_1 = kN \oplus kNy$, where $\langle x \rangle = C_4$, and $y=x^2$. This is $G$-graded and a crossed product.

I have to choose a set of units, one for each component. I choose $u_1 = 1$, and $u_y = y$. Then:

- $\alpha_1(r) = r$, so $\alpha_1 = \operatorname{Id}$.
- $\alpha_y(r) = yry^{-1} = r$, because $kG$ is commutative. So $\alpha_y= \operatorname{Id}$.
- $\gamma(g,h) = yy^{-1} = 1$.

so it looks like this is the crossed product identified by the trivial parameter set.

But now if I choose $G_2 = C_2 \times C_2$ and I repeat this procedure on $kG_2 = (kC_2) \oplus (kC_2)b$ (where $G_2 = \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$), I still get a trivial parameter set.

So it looks like $kC_4$ and $k(C_2 \times C_2)$ are the same crossed product of $kC_2$ with $C_2$... but this can't be right (can it?). Again, I am confused. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direct sum decomposition isn't a direct sum decomposition! If $x$ is the generator of $C_4$ so that $N = \langle x^2 \rangle$ then $k[N] x^2 = k[N]$. We should instead pick $k[C_4] = k[N] \oplus k[N] x$. If we then pick units $u_1 = 1, u_x = x$ (here I am identifying $x \in C_4$ with its image in the quotient $C_4/C_2$) then we get

$$\gamma(x, x) = u_x u_x u_{x^2}^{-1} = x^2 \neq 1$$

so the parameter set is interesting. In general if $G$ is abelian then the $\alpha$ all vanish but $\gamma$ will be where the action is.

Comment: Ah - what a silly mistake! You're right, thank you very much! Could you point me to a good resource to compute the cohomology groups where $\gamma$ lies? In this case since $U(A) \cong U(A/J(A)) \times (1+J(A))$ it would be:
$$H^2(C_2, U(Z(R))) = H^2(C_2, U(Z(R))/J(Z(R))) \oplus H^2(C_2, 1+J(Z(R))$$
and I think that I can show that the first summand is always trivial, due to $C_2$ being cyclic, so the question really becomes about cohomology with coefficients in $1 + J(Z(R))$.

Comment: Brown’s *Cohomology of Groups* should have everything you could ask for.